# Popup when user trying to uninstall my application

Tags: android

is that possible to prompt a popup to show message when user trying to uninstall my android application? i wanted to show some message my user when they uninstall. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as far as I know. The uninstalling process invokes none of your application code.